# Can't get new entries through twoway binding

Tags: maui

i have 4 entries in my view binded to an account with 4 properties ( site , description , username , password ) i've created a function in my viewmodel to update my database using an API but the field values are not changing as they should on an observable property.

```
        [ObservableProperty]
        Account account;

        public IAsyncRelayCommand UpdateAccountCommand => new AsyncRelayCommand(UpdateAccount);

        private async Task UpdateAccount()
        {
            try
            {
                Account.ChangeAccountDetails(Account.Site, Account.Description , Account.Username , Account.Password );

                await _apiService.Update(Account);

                await Application.Current.MainPage?.DisplayAlert("", "Account updated successfully", "OK");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HandleException("An error occurred while updating the account", ex);
            }
        }
```

here's my account class

```
public class Account
{
    private Account(string site, string description, string username, string password)
    {
        Site = site;
        Description = description;
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
    }

    [JsonConstructor]
    private Account(int id, string site, string description, string username, string password)
    {
        Id = id;
        Site = site;
        Description = description;
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    
    public string Site { get; private set; }

    public string Description { get; private set; }

    public string Username { get; private set; }

    public string Password { get; private set; }

    public static Account Create(
        string site,
        string description,
        string username,
        string password)
    {
        return new Account(site, description, username, password);
    }

    public void ChangePassword(string password)
    {
        Password = password;
    }

    public void ChangeAccountDetails(string site, string description, string username, string password)
    {
        Site = site;
        Description = description;
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
    }
}
```

and here's my view

```
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <Label Text="Site:" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="90"/>
                            <Entry Text="{Binding Account.Site, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Site" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" WidthRequest="180"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <Label Text="Description:" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="90"/>
                            <Entry Text="{Binding Account.Description, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Description" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" WidthRequest="180"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <Label Text="Username:" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="90"/>
                            <Entry Text="{Binding Account.Username, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Username"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" WidthRequest="180"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <Label Text="Password:" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="90"/>
                            <Entry Text="{Binding Account.Password, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True" WidthRequest="180"/>
                        </StackLayout>
```

i then have a button that calls updateaccountcommand

when debugging it shows the old values instead of the new ones i typed , i think im missing something that has to do with the observable property but im not so sure.

Answer (score 1):

The **private set** means that the properties can only be modified within the class itself.

*Firstly, I would try to make the setters public of the Account class* :

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    
    public string Site { get; set; } // Changed to public setter

    public string Description { get; set; } // Changed to public setter

    public string Username { get; set; } // Changed to public setter

    public string Password { get; set; } // Changed to public setter

    ...
}
```

*If the above does not work, try to implement the below code.*

**Step 1**: Implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** in **Account** Class

Implement the interface to notify the UI of changes.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class Account : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int id;
    private string site;
    private string description;
    private string username;
    private string password;

    public int Id
    {
        get => id;
        private set
        {
            id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Site
    {
        get => site;
        set
        {
            site = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get => description;
        set
        {
            description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get => username;
        set
        {
            username = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get => password;
        set
        {
            password = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    ...
}
```

**Step** 2 : Modify the **Constructors** and **Methods**

Ensure that your constructors and any methods that modifies properties use the property setters instead of directly setting the fields. This ensures that the **PropertyChanged** event is fired whenever a property value is changed.

For example, if you have a method to change account details, it should look like this:

```
public void ChangeAccountDetails(string site, string description, string username, string password)
{
    Site = site;
    Description = description;
    Username = username;
    Password = password;
}
```

**Step 3**: Update Your **ViewModel**

Ensure your ViewModel properly handles changes. Since you've already implemented [**ObservableProperty**] for the Account object in your ViewModel, changes to the Account properties should now automatically notify the UI to update thanks to the **INotifyPropertyChanged** implementation within the Account class.

Comment: ye apparently all i had to do was change the setters to public , it works as it should now. thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `ObservableObject` for `Account.cs` and add  `[ObservableProperty]` for the properties you want to change. Or implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged  for` Account.cs`

```
public partial class Account : ObservableObject
   {
       //other codes    

       public Account() { }


       public int Id { get; private set; }

       //public string Site { get; private set; }

       [ObservableProperty]
        private string? site;

       //public string Description { get; private set; }
       [ObservableProperty]
       private  string description;
       // public string Username { get; private set; }

       [ObservableProperty]
       private string username;

       //  public string Password { get; private set; }

       [ObservableProperty]
      private  string password;

       public static Account Create(
           string site,
           string description,
           string username,
           string password)
       {
           return new Account(site, description, username, password);
       }

       public void ChangePassword(string password)
       {
           Password = password;
       }

       public void ChangeAccountDetails(string site, string description, string username, string password)
       {
           Site = site;
           Description = description;
           Username = username;
           Password = password;
       }
    }
```

As a test, I created a view model, and it works on my side.

```
public partial class MyViewModel: ObservableObject
{

    [ObservableProperty]
    private Account myAccount;

    public IAsyncRelayCommand UpdateAccountCommand => new AsyncRelayCommand(UpdateAccount);


    public MyViewModel() {

        MyAccount = new Account();
    }

    private async Task UpdateAccount()
    {
        try
        {
           // MyAccount.ChangeAccountDetails(Account.Site, Account.Description, Account.Username, Account.Password);
            MyAccount.ChangeAccountDetails("111", "123" , "333", "444");


           // await _apiService.Update(Account);

            await Application.Current.MainPage?.DisplayAlert("", "Account updated successfully", "OK");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //HandleException("An error occurred while updating the account", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**

To make the code clearer, I replaced the following code

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    Account account;
```

with:

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    private Account myAccount;
```

So, we need change the xaml code to as follows:

```
     <Entry Text="{Binding MyAccount.Site, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```